# A way to read table data from Mysql to Pig

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-pig

Everyone know that Pig have supported [DBStorage](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/branches/branch-0.8/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/DBStorage.java?view=markup), 
but they are only supported load results from Pig to mysql like that

```
STORE data INTO DBStorage('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'dbc:mysql://host/db', 'INSERT ...');
```

But Please show me the way to read table from mysql like that

```
data = LOAD 'my_table' AS DBStorage('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'dbc:mysql://host/db', 'SELECT * FROM my_table');
```

Here is my code

```
public class DBLoader extends LoadFunc {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private ArrayList mProtoTuple = null;
    private Connection con;
    private String jdbcURL;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private int batchSize;
    private int count = 0;
    private String query;
    ResultSet result;
    protected TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();

    public DBLoader() {
    }

    public DBLoader(String driver, String jdbcURL, String user, String pass,
            String query) {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("can't load DB driver:" + driver, e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't load DB Driver", e);
        }
        this.jdbcURL = jdbcURL;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.query = query;

    }

    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new TextInputFormat();
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean next = false;

        try {
            next = result.next();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!next)
            return null;
        int numColumns = 0;
        // Get result set meta data
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
        try {
            rsmd = result.getMetaData();
            numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {

            try {
                Object field = result.getObject(i);

                switch (DataType.findType(field)) {
                case DataType.NULL:

                    mProtoTuple.add(null);

                    break;

                case DataType.BOOLEAN:
                    mProtoTuple.add((Boolean) field);

                    break;

                case DataType.INTEGER:
                    mProtoTuple.add((Integer) field);

                    break;

                case DataType.LONG:
                    mProtoTuple.add((Long) field);

                    break;

                case DataType.FLOAT:
                    mProtoTuple.add((Float) field);

                    break;

                case DataType.DOUBLE:
                    mProtoTuple.add((Double) field);

                    break;

                case DataType.BYTEARRAY:
                    byte[] b = ((DataByteArray) field).get();
                    mProtoTuple.add(b);

                    break;
                case DataType.CHARARRAY:
                    mProtoTuple.add((String) field);

                    break;
                case DataType.BYTE:
                    mProtoTuple.add((Byte) field);

                    break;

                case DataType.MAP:
                case DataType.TUPLE:
                case DataType.BAG:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot store a non-flat tuple "
                            + "using DbStorage");

                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown datatype "
                            + DataType.findType(field));

                }

            } catch (Exception ee) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ee);
            }
        }

        Tuple t = mTupleFactory.newTuple(mProtoTuple);
        mProtoTuple.clear();
        return t;

    }

    @Override
    public void prepareToRead(RecordReader arg0, PigSplit arg1)
            throws IOException {

        con = null;
        if (query == null) {
            throw new IOException("SQL Insert command not specified");
        }
        try {
            if (user == null || pass == null) {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL);
            } else {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, pass);
            }
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            result = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Unable to connect to JDBC @" + jdbcURL);
            throw new IOException("JDBC Error", e);
        }
        count = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location);

    }

    class MyDBInputFormat extends InputFormat<NullWritable, NullWritable>{

        @Override
        public RecordReader<NullWritable, NullWritable> createRecordReader(
                InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext arg0) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I try many times to write UDF but not success.....

Answer (score 2):

Like you say, `DBStorage` only supports saving results to a database.

To load data from MySQL you could look into a project called [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) (that copies data from a database to HDFS), or you could perform a mysql dump and then copy the file into HDFS. Both ways required some interaction and cannot be directly used from inside Pig.

A third option would be to look into writing a Pig LoadFunc (you say your tried to write a UDF). It shouldn't be too difficult, you'll need to pass much the same options as DBStorage (driver, connection credentials and a SQL query to execute), and you can probably use some result set metadata inspection to auto generate a schema too.

Comment: hi, thanks you. But as I mention before, I only want to load directly used from inside Pig. I post my code extend from LoadFunc as you said. When I run my code from big, its always throws exception.

Comment: Then please add the exception you are seeing

Comment: @phuongdo Are you success in writing Pig LoadFunc for loading data from mysql?