# Need some expert help in a Hadoop Hive Pig Scenario

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am still in process of learning Hadoop and have come across a specific situation:
I have two tables, first Table A in mySQL with columns: email and address, while the second Table B inside HDFS with columns: id, email and address. I have to look for email in both tables, and update Table B with the new rows from Table A (the email which are not present in Table B, are the new record entries in Table A and therefore have to be moved in Table B).

Can I solve this problem using Pig or using Hive script? Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently loading a MySql table in to HDFS would need some effort using Sqoop or a custom load UDF. Look at this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942739/a-way-to-read-table-data-from-mysql-to-pig)

Once you have the data in HDFS, it is a matter of doing a left (or right) join and get the difference in rows and creating a new relation as needed and store in HDFS.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to move data using SQOOP but got stuck with a new error. Do I need to create an empty table in mysql with proper columns  before exporting data from HDFS to mysql? or the table will be created automatically?