# Is it possible to connect mysql with hadoop without using mysql applier?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I want to retrieve data from my mysql database using hadoop without using sqoop/hive or mysql applier. Is it possible? If yes ,then how?

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942739/a-way-to-read-table-data-from-mysql-to-pig

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom MR job using [DBInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html) or [DataDrivenDBInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/db/DataDrivenDBInputFormat.html)

Comment: can you provide any sources for that?? @Magham Ravi

Comment: i found the following useful link https://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/database-access-with-apache-hadoop/

Comment: am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver exception